# show or hide button if some radio input is have fill

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button

I have quiz with input form like this:

```
 <form method="post">
    //for question 1
    <div class="input-group radio">
    <label>
    <input type="radio" id="radio" name="quiz1" class="radio" value="answer a"/><span>a</span>
    </label></div>

    <div class="input-group radio">
    <label>
    <input type="radio" id="radio" name="quiz1" class="radio" value="answer b"/><span>a</span>
    </label></div>

    <div class="input-group radio">
    <label>
    <input type="radio" id="radio" name="quiz1" class="radio" value="answer c"/><span>a</span>
    </label></div>

    //for question 2
    <div class="input-group radio">
    <label>
    <input type="radio" id="radio" name="quiz2" class="radio" value="answer a"/><span>a</span>
    </label></div>

    <div class="input-group radio">
    <label>
    <input type="radio" id="radio" name="quiz2" class="radio" value="answer b"/><span>a</span>
    </label></div>

    <div class="input-group radio">
    <label>
    <input type="radio" id="radio" name="quiz2" class="radio" value="answer c"/><span>a</span>
    </label></div>

    <input type="submit" value="submit">
```

how to hide the submit button, if I have not answered all radio question?

I have this function, but not work well

```
  $(function() {
    $('form:radio[class=radio]').on('click coba', function() {
        $('#submit').toggle($('#radio').prop('checked'));
    }).trigger('coba');
});
```

Comment: Identifiers in HTML must be unique.

Answer (score 1):

Try using jQuery selectors in order to achieve this. Try the code below:

```js
$(function() {
    
    $('form input:radio').on('change', function() {
        if($(":radio", "#myForm").length/3 === $(":radio:checked", "#myForm").length){
            $('#submit-form').show();
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" id="myForm" >
    //for question 1
    <div class="input-group radio">
    <label>
    <input type="radio" id="radio" name="quiz1" class="radio" value="answer a"/><span>a</span>
    </label></div>

    <div class="input-group radio">
    <label>
    <input type="radio" id="radio" name="quiz1" class="radio" value="answer b"/><span>a</span>
    </label></div>

    <div class="input-group radio">
    <label>
    <input type="radio" id="radio" name="quiz1" class="radio" value="answer c"/><span>a</span>
    </label></div>

    //for question 2
    <div class="input-group radio">
    <label>
    <input type="radio" id="radio" name="quiz2" class="radio" value="answer a"/><span>a</span>
    </label></div>

    <div class="input-group radio">
    <label>
    <input type="radio" id="radio" name="quiz2" class="radio" value="answer b"/><span>a</span>
    </label></div>

    <div class="input-group radio">
    <label>
    <input type="radio" id="radio" name="quiz2" class="radio" value="answer c"/><span>a</span>
    </label></div>

    <input type="submit" id="submit-form" style="display:none" value="submit">
```

Comment: I would recommend to group question and answers individually by wrapping it up with a DIV or something so that selection and calculation goes easy and more meaningful.

Answer (score 0):

I think you must use proper use of class and id attribute before create the JS code.

- You actually have no way to identify which radio buttons belong to the first question and which belong to the second, at least wrap every question in a container
- don't give the same class name to radio inputs and to their div wrappers, there is no need to do it. maybe leave class "radio" for all radio elements and give the class "radio-wrapper" to the divs
- most important: don't use the same ID for multiple elements. It's really wrong: why all your radio inputs have the "radio" id? id MUST be unique, otherwise you use class

Comment: thannks for respon, i do it because i have this values question from database, and all of my question is radio now. can you show to me the best? please

Answer (score 0):

A quick a dirty way would be:

```
$(function() {

    //hide submit button
    $(":submit").hide();

    //The script needs to know how many radio button each group has
    var groupRadioCount = $(":radio[name='quiz1']").length;

    //All radio buttons (where name starts with 'quiz')
    var $allRadio = $(":radio[name^='quiz']");

    //All radio checked length
    var allSelectedLen = $allRadio.length / groupRadioCount;

    $('form :radio').on('change', function() {
        $(":submit").toggle( $allRadio.filter(":checked").length ===  allSelectedLen);
    });
});
```

[**A Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/pszuvtyw/)

P.S. I have removed the `ID` attribute from your radio buttons as an `ID` must be unique in any given document!

Answer (score 0):

In your html form put id in your form and submit button... And every id of your radio button must be unique... you can change your id's by id="radio1" id="radio2" id="radio3" and so on.. you said, you have a submit button, why is that your submit is an input.

```
<form id="main-form" method="post">
<button id="Submit" type="submit" value="submit"></button>
```

for the id of radios and so on

```
//for question 1
    <div class="input-group radio">
    <label>
    <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="quiz1" class="radio" value="answer a"/><span>a</span>
    </label></div>

    <div class="input-group radio">
    <label>
    <input type="radio" id="radio2" name="quiz1" class="radio" value="answer b"/><span>a</span>
    </label></div>

    <div class="input-group radio">
    <label>
    <input type="radio" id="radio3" name="quiz1" class="radio" value="answer c"/><span>a</span>
    </label></div>
```

After that you may ask another question for the function of submit button

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example implementation given your current HTML code:

```
$(function () {
    $("form").submit(function (event) {
        answer_groups = {};
        $self = $(this);

        // First we group the radio names
        $self.find(':radio').map(function (key, radio) {
            answer_groups[radio.name] = true;
        })

        // Then we check and see if there exists an answer for that group
        Object.keys(answer_groups).map(function (group_name) {
            // if not, then cancel the form being submitted.
            if ($self.find(':radio[name="' + group_name + '"]:checked').length <= 0) {
                alert('You must fill all questions before proceeding.');
                event.preventDefault();
                return false;
            }
        })
    });
})
```

The idea here is simply to iterate through the radio groups and check for the value of each of those. If one does not exist, then cancel the form being submitted and return an alert (or error of some kind).

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/t1s8e5ae/